# Iterate an RDD[A] where A contains List[B]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, map-function

I have object A which contains a List of objects B, I want to get something from every B object (ex: B.id), more or less like 2 for each combined.

Example code:

```
rddA.flatMap(
  a => a.listB.map(
    b => (a.id, b.id)
  )
)
```

Comment: Edited my answer, please check it out!

Answer (score 0):

This actually works, my problem was that i call a method that uses another map thus failing.

```
case class Car( id :Long, listWheels : List[Wheel])

case class Wheel( id : Long)

rddCars.flatMap(
    a => a.listWheels.map(
     b => (a.id, b.id, getBrandFromSerial(serialToBrandMap,b.id))
    )
 )

getBrandFromSerial(serialToBrandMap: RDD[(Int, String)], id : Int) : String = {
   val a = serialToBrandMap.filter(_._1 == id)
   val b = a.map(_._2).top(1)
   b(0)
}
```

The result expected is a RDD[(Int,Int,String)] with Car id, Wheel id and Wheel Brand on a Tuple3.

EDIT: Sample input/output

Input:

```
val wheels1 = List(Wheel(1),Wheel(1),Wheel(2), Wheel(2)
val wheels2 = List(Wheel(3),Wheel(3),Wheel(2), Wheel(2)
val rddCars : RDD[Car] = sparkContect.parallelize(List(Car(1,wheels1), Car(2, wheels2)))

val serialToBrandList : List[(Int, String)] = List((1,"Brand1"), (2,"Brand2"),(3,"Brand3"))
val serialToBrandMap : RDD[(Int, String)] = sparkContect.parallelize( serialToBrandList)
```

Output:

```
 (1,1,Brand1),(1,1,Brand1),(1,2,Brand2)....(2,3,Brand3) and so on
```

Comment: Hi, rdd is a RDD[(Int, String)], and its simulating a Map(Int,String). And what i want is a RDD[(Int,Int,String)].

Comment: A and B are objects. A for example can be a Car that has a List of Wheels  (B), that have a atributte (like serial number). The rdd, simulates a Map which has a combination of (Int,String), and callMethod can be getBrand()  where given the serial number, it returns the brand of the wheel stored in the rdd.

Comment: Input and expected data??

Comment: I already did explain the input and output data as generic types, do you need like a real example?

Comment: yes please, that's the reason there are no replies till now

Comment: sample input data and your expected output. It's easy for people to help you here!!